# Mostrar cajas correctamente en versión móvil

Tags: css, wordpress

Tengo una web https://www.pantallasamigas.net/ con un diseño que se ajusta de forma automática a móvil pero la parte final de los recuadros (Recursos Educativos) hace una cosa rara en versiones móviles.

se muestran los recuadros por columnas:
Primero: Videojuegos en familia, Respeto imágenes íntimas, Pilar y su Celular

quiero que se muestren por filas:
Primero: Videojuegos en familia, Salud Digital, Modo avión

**¿Qué tendría que añadir en el CSS o cambiar para que se muestre correctamente en la versión móvil?**

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], para que podamos ofrecer algún tipo de ayuda es recomendable agregues el código mínimo necesario para poder reproducir tu problema

Comment: ¿qué trozo de código necesitas? Gracias.